# How Do I Highlight Rows Of Data? Python Pandas issue

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm trying to highlight any row where the cookie flavor is chocolate. How do I do this? I'm trying to use df.style, but not having any luck...

```
import pandas as pd

Excel_file = "Cookies2.xlsx"

x = pd.read_excel(Excel_file)

sorted_by_Cookie_Boxes_Sold = x.sort_values(['Cookie_Boxes_Sold'], 
ascending=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_by_Cookie_Boxes_Sold)

df.style
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the rule first:

```
def color_chocolate_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val == 'chocolate' else 'black'
    return 'color: {}'.format(color)
```

Then apply it:

```
result = df.style.applymap(color_chocolate_red)
```

For entire row you can use this:

```
def highlight_row(x):
    df = x.copy()
    mask = df['column'] == 'chocolate'
    df.loc[mask, :] = 'color: red'
    df.loc[~mask,:] = 'color: black'
    return df
```

Comment: How do I make it appear? Do I write: print(result)?

Comment: Exactly like that.

Comment: When I try that, the table doesnt appear--only this comes up: <pandas.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0000000009993160>

Comment: You must be using `Spyder` and the styler object can't be rendered in spyder's ipython console.

Comment: I'm using a jupyter notebook

Comment: Have you tried just `result` instead of `print(result)`?