# Highlighting excel cells based on the cell values using pandas dataframe and xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a csv file. After doing certain process, it has to be saved as an excel file.

I am opening it as pandas dataframe and after doing some cleaning (renaming and rearranging columns, dropping few columns), i have to replace null values or if the cell value is `"N/A"` to `"DN"`. Currently i am using two lines of code for this.

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace = True)
df.replace('N/A', np.nan, inplace = True)
df = df.fillna("DN")
```

Then, i have to highlight cells which has the value "DN" with yellow color

I am trying with the code mentioned in this post [How Do I Highlight Rows Of Data? Python Pandas issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638372/how-do-i-highlight-rows-of-data-python-pandas-issue). But in the output excel nothing is getting highlighted. Below is the code i am currently working with

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace = True)
df.replace('N/A', np.nan, inplace = True)
df = df.fillna("NA")
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)

def high_color(val):
    color = 'yellow' if val == 'NA' else ''
    return 'color: {}'.format(color)
result = df.style.applymap(high_color)

writer_orig = pd.ExcelWriter(out_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer_orig, sheet_name='report', index=True, index_label="S_No", freeze_panes=(1,1))

workbook  = writer_orig.book
worksheet = writer_orig.sheets['report']
# Add a header format.
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'fg_color': '#ffcccc',
    'border': 1})
    
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
writer_orig.close()
```

Any kind of suggestions will be greatly helpful.

Comment: You have to use `result` (the Styler) and not `df` => `result.to_excel(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export to excel with `result` Styler:

```
# Demo
def high_color(val):
    return 'background-color: yellow' if val == 'NA' else None

result = df.style.applymap(high_color)
result.to_excel('styler1.xlsx')
df.to_excel('styler2.xlsx')
```

Export from `result`

[image]

Export from `df`

[image]

Comment: Glad to help. Sometimes we don't see mistakes anymore when we don't take a break :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't save a [*Styler Object*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Styler-Object-and-HTML) to an Excel spreadsheet by using [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#).

> class pandas.ExcelWriter(path, engine=None, date_format=None,
> datetime_format=None, mode='w', storage_options=None,
> if_sheet_exists=None, engine_kwargs=None, **kwargs)
> Class for writing **DataFrame objects** into excel sheets.

You need to use [`worksheet.conditional_format`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) from [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter) to highlight a value in every cell. Also, you can pass `na_values` as a *kwarg* to [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to automatically consider a list of values as `NaN`.

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/inputfile.csv', na_values=['', 'N/A']).fillna('DN')

l = df.columns.get_indexer(df.columns).tolist()
xshape = list(map(xl_col_to_name, [e+1 for e in l])) 
max_row, max_col = df.shape

with pd.ExcelWriter("/tmp/outputfile.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report', index=True,
                index_label='S_No', freeze_panes=(1,1))
    
    wb = writer.book
    ws = writer.sheets['report']
    
    format_header = wb.add_format({'bold': True, 'fg_color': '#ffcccc', 'border': 1})
    for idx, col in enumerate(['S_No'] + list(df.columns)):
        ws.write(0, idx, col, format_header)  
        
    format_dn = wb.add_format({'bg_color':'yellow', 'font_color': 'black'})
    ws.conditional_format(f'{xshape[0]}2:{xshape[-1]}{str(max_row+1)}',
                                 {'type': 'cell', 'criteria': '==',
                                  'value': '"DN"', 'format': format_dn})
```

Output :

[image]
[image]

Comment: This code worked fine for me. But since i already written the code - as mentioned above - i couldn't use this.

Comment: No worries, it was no more than a proposition to solve your problem ;)